# How to pass data from function received from child component and then pass it to another child?

Tags: angular, data-binding, eventemitter

I have a header component with two child component one is searchbar and another is search-list.
Now I am able to receive input from the searchbar component to header via emit function but how can I pass that recevied data to another child using @Input?

searchbar component

```
sendMessage() {
    this.messageEvent.emit(this.searchText)
  }
```

header component

```
message: string;

  receiveMessage($event) {
    this.message = $event
  }
```

search-list component

```
@Input() message: any;
```

header HTML

```
<div *ngIf="message">
  <app-search-list [message]="message" ></app-search-list>
</div>
```

I am getting 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined.

In searchbar component I have an input field, when i type there i am using pipes to search data...
so what I am doing is...
the moment I type something, I get that text, pass it to parent component and then pass it to another child component where I call that pipeline to make the query for search.

Thank you

Comment: look like you are missing something

Comment: resolved it, i am such a newbie... Actually, I wasn't passing rest of the data where i am concating them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of routing the message through the header, you can use a singleton service that can broadcast it to subscribed components.

Create a data service that is responsible for broadcasting the value:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  private value: string;
  listeners = [];

  constructor() {
    this.value = '';
  }

  onDataChange(fn) {
    this.listeners.push(fn);
  }

  set setData(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.listeners.forEach((fn) => {
      fn(value);
    });
  }
}
```

In each of your component where you want to perform communication, inject the data service.

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
```

You can set the value of the data in a component like so:

```
this.dataService.setData= 'New value';
```

You can then subscribe to the value change event of the data service in a different component on ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.onDataChange((value) => {
         this.data = value;
    });
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z5va6z)

Comment: In searchbar component I have an input field, when i type there i am using pipes to search data...
so what I am doing is...
the moment I type something, I get that text, pass it to parent controller and then pass it to another child component where I call that pipeline to make the query for search.

Comment: I'd recommend performing the search in a service, which you can inject straight into the search bar component. Then, you can use the data service above to share any data with other components.